# How to check who killed Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Want to know who killed any particular Jenkins job. Please share any script logic or plugin so that we can check the same.

Comment: The aborted build logs should show who aborted it. Is that what you are asking ?

Comment: Thanks Ben. Yes, I'm looking who aborted the job. Can you please explain little bit more. Where i can see aborted build log.

Comment: For each jenkins job there should be logs for each build. Can you check the specific aborted build logs ?

Answer (score 0):

Will answer your question fully to be as helpful to the community as possible.

Some terminology:

- When you create a New Item from the RHS menu you are creating what used to be (and to my mind still is) called a "job" or a "project".
- A "job" has many "builds", which get numbered starting at one and incrementing by 1.

An aborted build will be denoted with a grey orb next to the build.  The status of the latest (highest numbered) build of a job is the current status of the job.  If an orb is "blinking" then it is currently building.

- If the last build failed and it is currently building it will be a blinking red orb
- If the last build was unstable and it is currently building it will be a blinking yellow orb.
- If the last build succeeded and it is currently building it will be a blinking blue (or green if you have the green-balls plugin installed) orb.

If the job is not currently building it will simply not be blinking but the same rules apply as to the color of the orb.

The status of the job is the status of the last completed build.

Now to find out who aborted a build navigate to an aborted build of a job you are interested in and:

- you should see either on that page `Aborted by user Joe Bloggs`; or
- Click "Console Output" link in RHS menu and scroll toward the bottom to see the same message.

HTH